# Passing a dictionary to a function, manipulating the values and returning a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a func calculate_tax that should take a *name:salary* pair as an argument, calculates the tax then returns a dictionary of  *name:total_tax* pair.However, it seem not to calculate tax correctly.What could I be doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
def calculate_tax(**data):
    for key in data:
        if data[key] > 0 and data[key] <= 1000:
            data[key] = 0
        elif data[key] > 1000 and data[key] <= 10000:
            data[key] += (data[key]-1000)*0.1
        elif data[key] > 10000 and data[key] <= 20200:
            data[key] += (data[key]-10000)*0.15
        elif data[key] > 20200 and data[key] <= 30750:
            data[key] += (data[key]-20200)*0.2
        elif data[key] > 30750 and data[key] <= 50000:
            data[key] += (data[key]-30750)*0.25
        elif data[key] > 50000:
            data[key] += (data[key]-50000)*0.3
    return data
```

The tax rates are:

```
Yearly Income: 0 - 1000
Tax Rate: 0%

Yearly Income: 1,001 - 10,000
Tax Rate: 10%

Yearly Income: 10,001 - 20,200
Tax Rate: 15%

Yearly Income: 20,201 - 30,750
Tax Rate: 20%

Yearly Income: 30,751 - 50,000
Tax Rate: 25%

Yearly Income: Over 50,000
Tax Rate: 30%
```

For example, when given:

```
{'Ken':500,'Patrick':20500,'Winnie':70000}
```

it should return Patrick's tax as `2490`

Comment: the result am getting instead is : {'Patrick': 20560.0, 'Ken': 0, 'Winnie': 76000.0} which appears to be wrong

Comment: `Patrick':20500 - it should return Patrick's tax as 2490` - why? It will be `20500 + (20500 - 20200) * 0.2 = 2560`

Comment: @Hillux Could provide the way you want to compute the taxes using mathematical expression? You missed up with operation order precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong method in calculate_tax, as $2490 as tax, it was **passed 3 levels tax base**.

Therefore, you should calculate the **income - tax base** till the rest is no need to pay tax.

You may use `while` loop to do that.

BTW, I did it for you=]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
def calculate_tax(data_dict):
    for person in data_dict:
        income_need_to_pay_tax = data_dict[person]
        tax = 0
        while income_need_to_pay_tax > 1000:
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 50000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 50000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.3
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 30750:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 30750
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.25
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 20200:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 20200
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.2
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 10000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 10000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.15
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 1000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 1000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base * 0.1
        print(person, tax)
```

> Patrick 2490.0
>   Ken 0
>   Winnie 15352.5

Comment: this is really nice but I need the function to return a dictionary

Comment: just make `data_dict[person] = tax` after the while loop, it should not be difficult to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
def calculate_tax(data_dict):
    data_output = []

    for person in data_dict:
        income_need_to_pay_tax = data_dict[person]
        tax = 0
        while income_need_to_pay_tax > 1000:
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 50000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 50000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.3
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 30750:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 30750
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.25
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 20200:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 20200
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.2
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 10000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 10000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base*0.15
            if income_need_to_pay_tax > 1000:
                income_in_tax_base = income_need_to_pay_tax - 1000
                income_need_to_pay_tax -= income_in_tax_base
                tax += income_in_tax_base * 0.1
            data_output.append((person, tax))        
    return dict(data_output)
```